# Selecting sum of single column depending on two columns on same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, aggregate-functions

I have a table very similar to the one below. `p1` and `p2` on the table refer to id of player on an another table.

```
id score p1 p2 date
-- ----- -- -- ----
1  12    1  2  2011.10.21
2  23    3  4  2011.10.22
3  21    1  3  2011.10.23
4  35    5  1  2011.10.24
5  11    2  3  2011.10.25
```

What I want to do is the get the player id (p1 or p2) with highest score. My solution is something like `select sum(score)` but I can't form a query because a player may appear in both p1 or p2 columns.

Also a bigger problem is when I want to sort scores from highest to lowest. I dont know what to do. How can I sum and sort a score if I need to group to separate columns? The result I want is similar to this output:

```
pID score times_played
--- ----- ------------
1   68    3
3   55    3
5   35    1
2   23    2
4   23    1
```

Is my database design flawed? If there is a more intelligent way I'd like to know. Should I need seperate single queries so I can merge them on PHP or something?

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers.

PS: I couldnt think a nice subject. Feel free to edit.

Comment: One simplification would be to insert two records for each score and have only one playerid column.

Comment: How do you know to which player does the score belongs to? You only have one score column and 2 players.

Comment: @Icarus They are a team of players. When they play together thet get the same score. But a player may team up with another player for another game.

Comment: So the highest score will belong to two people?   What do you do in the event of two rows with the same score?

Comment: @Sparky It is possible that another team may score same as a previous score. And a player may form any number of teams. In the end what I need is the total score for every individual player.

Comment: @Sinan It seems that Sparky and I interpreted your question pretty much the same way so I have undeleted my initial answer but I feel that if the score belongs to 2 players perhaps the score should be divided by 2. If that's the case; you can just divide by 2 the score column of my inner select on my last query

Comment: @Icarus Thanks. I had a chance to copy your answer and it seemed to work. But a few moments later it was deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the players in one column as so:

```
select id, score, p1 as player, date from yourtable
union all
select id, score, p2 as player, date from yourtable
```

You now have players in one column. You can do this to get the score sum for all players

```
select sum(score), player from (
    select id, score, p1 as player, date from yourtable
    union all
    select id, score, p2 as player, date from yourtable
) group by player
```

Now, you say that you also want to know how many times the player played and sort them in descending order:

```
select sum(score), player, count(*) as timesPlayed from (
    select id, score, p1 as player, date from yourtable
    union all
    select id, score, p2 as player, date from yourtable
) group by player order by sum(score) desc
```

Comment: This works as I need. If I understand correctly UNION basically creates a temporary table and then we select on that dataset right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get players with highest score (disregarding ties)

```
select id,p1,p2 
from table t1
join (select max(score) as MaxS) xx on xx.MaxS = t1.Score
limit 1
```

To get player total score, try this

```
select Player as pID,Sum(tot) as Score, count(*) as TimesPlayed
from
(
select p1 as Player,sum(score) as Tot
from table 
group by p1
union all
select p2,sum(score)
from table 
group by p2
) xx
Group by xx.Player
order by Score desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to using UNION (ALL) on the table, you could try something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE p.PlayerNumber WHEN 1 THEN t.p1 ELSE t.p2 END AS pID,
  SUM(t.score) AS score,
  COUNT(*) AS times_played
FROM atable t
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS PlayerNumber UNION ALL SELECT 2) p
GROUP BY
  pID /* this is probably MySQL-specific; most, if not all, other major
database systems would require repeating the entire pID expression here, i.e.
GROUP BY
  CASE p.PlayerNumber WHEN 1 THEN t.p1 ELSE t.p2 END
*/
ORDER BY
  score DESC,
  times_played DESC  /* this is based on your result set;
                        you might want to omit it or change it to ASC */
```

---

**UPDATE**, in an answer to a question in the comments: joining the result set to the `user` table:

```
SELECT
  `user`.*,  /* you should probably specify
                the necessary columns explicitly */
  totals.score,
  totals.times_played
FROM `user` u
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      CASE p.PlayerNumber WHEN 1 THEN t.p1 ELSE t.p2 END AS pID,
      SUM(t.score) AS score,
      COUNT(*) AS times_played
    FROM atable t
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS PlayerNumber UNION ALL SELECT 2) p
    GROUP BY
      pID
  ) totals ON user.id = totals.pID
ORDER BY
  totals.score DESC,
  totals.times_played DESC
```

Comment: This works just fine. However I have no idea which is better or is there performance gain/loss between the two. Is there a gain by avoiding UNION(ALL) ?

Comment: Well, I would expect some gain, because when you do `SELECT ... FROM atable GROUP BY ... UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM atable GROUP BY ...`, the table is scanned twice, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: One thing. How do I relate pID to user database. If I add `, user where pID = user.id` It says "unknown column pID"

Comment: @Sinan: I would use the result of the query as a derived table and join it to `user`. Please see my update.